# Intuition behind starting from the bottom right (instead of the top left) in this DP

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was solving [Dungeon Game](https://leetcode.com/problems/dungeon-game/description/) on LeetCode.  While I was able to come up with the recurrence relation (and determine that it was a DP question in the first place), what is the intuition behind starting from the bottom right, as shown in a highly upvoted solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int calculateMinimumHP(vector<vector<int> > &dungeon) {
        int M = dungeon.size();
        int N = dungeon[0].size();
        // hp[i][j] represents the min hp needed at position (i, j)
        // Add dummy row and column at bottom and right side
        vector<vector<int> > hp(M + 1, vector<int>(N + 1, INT_MAX));
        hp[M][N - 1] = 1;
        hp[M - 1][N] = 1;
        for (int i = M - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = N - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                int need = min(hp[i + 1][j], hp[i][j + 1]) - dungeon[i][j];
                hp[i][j] = need <= 0 ? 1 : need;
            }
        }
        return hp[0][0];
    }
};
```

I thought it to be pretty similar to the [Unique Paths](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/description/) question, and hence started solving from the top left (but it doesn't retrieve correct results).  My solution (if at all required) is:

```
class Solution {
    public int calculateMinimumHP(int[][] dungeon) {
        if(dungeon==null || dungeon.length==0 || dungeon[0]==null || dungeon[0].length==0)
            return -1;

        int maxVal = 0;
        int[][] dp = new int[dungeon.length][dungeon[0].length];
        dp[0][0] = dungeon[0][0];
        for(int i=1; i<dungeon.length; i++)
            dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + dungeon[i][0];
        for(int i=1; i<dungeon[0].length; i++)
            dp[0][i] = dp[0][i-1] + dungeon[0][i];

        int chosenOne=0;
        for(int i=1; i<dungeon.length; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<dungeon[0].length; j++) {
                if(dp[i-1][j] < 0 && dp[i][j-1] < 0) {
                    chosenOne = Math.max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]);
                }
                else {
                    if(dp[i-1][j] > 0 && dp[i][j-1] > 0) {
                        chosenOne = Math.min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]);
                    }
                    else {
                        chosenOne = (dp[i-1][j]>0?dp[i-1][j]:dp[i][j-1]);
                    }
                }
                dp[i][j] = dungeon[i][j] + chosenOne;
                maxVal = Math.min(maxVal, dp[i][j]);
            }
        }

        return maxVal+1;
    }
}
```

One of the comments [here by 'JaiMataDi'](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/6912/c-dp-solution/10) mentions that it is so because we don't know the initial health point of the knight.  But how about the approach that *I* used?

**To be precise, could some one please point out the intuition behind why we start at the bottom right and not the top left?**

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a very good venue for online judge questions, often because it's hard to fit both the (usually lengthy) problem description and code attempt in the question. However, the reason for starting in the bottom right is likely because of a top-down style memoization approach. e.g. "least dangerous path to get to me is minimum of least dangerous path to get to my neighbors above and to the left".

Comment: @AndyG, I have had a good experience _so far_ with asking competitive programming questions on SO (I owe _all_ my reputation to it (although it is too little)).  As for my question, the title should ideally be sufficient along with the top code that I have posted.  Also, could you please elaborate about the top-down approach?

Comment: @AndyG, btw, is it top-down or bottom-up?  Top-down in what sense?

Comment: Top down. The solution to the problem depends on the solution to two subproblems etc. A bottom up approach solves the most basic subproblems first, and then solves the subproblems that depend on those, etc.  You could do it either way, it's just that some make more intuitive sense one way or the other.